# What is the best way to get the data from an array that is stored in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

Below as you can see in my code i created a input field for users that i want to store inside of an array, which also i want to store that array into localstorage. Now i think that stored the values that i give trough the input field in localsorage , beacuse that i can see from my browser application in chrome. Now with this code i have some problem.

Each value that i add one by one as you can see in the picture below ,whenever i refresh the browser , the values disapear from the browser? 
So if someone can help me out with my code i would appriciate a lot , and also give me some advice , since im very new to localstorage and cookies and i am trying to learn

```
    <input type="text" id="username"><br><br>
<input type="submit"  id="btn">

   <p id="demo"></p> 

<script>
    var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
    var user=document.getElementById("username");
    var names=[];

btn.onclick=function(){

    names.push(user.value);

    localStorage.setItem("names",JSON.stringify(names));

    var f =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names")); 

    var x;

    var i;

        for(i=0;i<f.length;i++){

            x+=f[i]+"<br>";

        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Assign empty string to x `var x = "";` Default values of declared variables in JS is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because you never assign a value to `x` prior to using it in `x+=f[i]+"<br>"`, so it gets the default value `undefined`, which is then converted to string. Assign `""` to `x` before the loop.

---

Side note: There's no need for `f` in that code at all. Just use `names`:

```
localStorage.setItem("names",JSON.stringify(names));
var x = "";
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    x += names[i] + "<br>";
}
```

You might also consider using `join` instead of a loop:

```
localStorage.setItem("names",JSON.stringify(names));
var x = names.join("<br>");
```

---

Beware that if any name is entered that contains a `<` or `&`, it could potentially mess up your output, since of course those characters start things that are special in HTML (tags and character references, respectively). To prevent that, you might use `map` before `join`:

```
localStorage.setItem("names",JSON.stringify(names));
var x = names.map(function(name) {
    return name.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}).join("<br>");
```

or in modern JavaScript:

```
localStorage.setItem("names",JSON.stringify(names));
const x = names.map(name => name.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;"))
               .join("<br>");
```

That's only valid if you're outputting to an element's body, as you are in that code; if you were outputting to an attribute value, it would be more complicated. (Some folks would also change `>` to `&gt;`, but there isn't any need to if, again, you're outputting to the body of an element and not within a tag.)